# Loading a PCD file from a directory using the specified path (the path contains a string which is the filename)

Tags: c++, file, loading, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am trying to load a pcd file from a directory, so I am getting the filename and then adding this filename to the path.

I know that the filename can be directly specified in the path but I am doing this because the filename will vary.

```
      //getting the filename
      string ls = "3989440000.pcd"
      chdir("/home");
      path="/home/usr/pcd/" + ls;

    // Fill in the cloud data
       if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> (path.c_str(), *cloud) == -1) 
      {
        PCL_ERROR ("Couldn't read file test_pcd.pcd \n");
        return (-1);
      }
```

This is the error I am facing.

[pcl::PCDReader::readHeader] Could not find file '/home/usr/pcd/3989440000.pcd
'.
Couldn't read file test_pcd.pcd

Comment: What is your question? The error message is pretty clear to me. What don't you understand?

Comment: Even though the path to the file is correct I am not able to load the file.

Comment: If I specify the path in the load, like this it works.     pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> ('/home/usr/pcd/3989440000.pcd' , *cloud)                                                                                                                    But if I give this it does not load,    pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> (path.c_str(), *cloud)

Comment: That's very weird and shouldn't be the case. Are you sure sure that the `ls` string matches the file on the disk?